# What is the meaning of homey?

Tags: meaning

I came across the word *homey* in the movie Coach Carter. That's how it was:

> - Lyle, why don't you shut up your mouth before I close it for good?
> - You didn't do shit either the whole game.
> - What, homey? [...]

Comment: Related question: [Pinole homey meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/55362/9161)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Homey* (usually spelled ‹homie› to distinguish it from the word meaning “homelike, comfortable”) is a diminutive form of *homeboy*, meaning originally someone from your own hometown or neighborhood but in contemporary urban slang anyone of your own culture, and by extension any comrade or colleague. As a term of address it is now in such wide use that in many cases it means little more than *guy*, and may be used (as in your example) with no implication of affection.

There’s an article on the word at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homie) where the complex origin of the term is discussed.

Comment: Will it sound a little offensive if I come to one of my colleague and say "Hey, homey. What're doing right here?"

Comment: I don't think it would be considered "Offensive" but it's definitely not very professional. The word has connotations with thugs in my mind.

Comment: The fact that you describe this person as a colleague says you should probably not refer to him as homie.  Save it for your 4-5 closest friends when you're in a jocular mood.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv The core function of slang is to assert membership in the speech community which uses it, so you should use it only within that community and avoid using it until there is clear evidence that you are accepted into that community.

Comment: I, BigHomie, approve this answer.

Comment: @BigHomie Thanks, man. I'm always a little nervous when I pontificate about the slang used by people fifty years younger than I am.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv - Unless you're on very good terms with your colleague, I'd recommend against it. The problem is that "homie" can also be used ironically (and disrespectfully). In this use, it suggests either that you think the person you're talking to is, as others have put it, "a thug", or that you think that he wants to be a thug. So your colleague might think you're dissing him. It would depend entirely on how you get along with him and your tone of voice.