# Pinole homey meaning

Tags: meaning

From the Coach Carter movie:

Three members of the basketball team are trying to pick up three girls while another three guys come to them and say that they are their girls. They start fighting while another member of the basketball team comes to them with a gun and says:

> - Let's do it homey. You feel me right now? Pinole homey. Feel me?

What does *Pinole homey* mean?

Comment: I've never seen the movie, but it does take place in California, and there is [a city named Pinole in California](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinole,_California). It could be just referring to the town the boy is from, because one of the definitions of [homey](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/homeboy#homeboy_1) is a "a boy or man from the same town, neighborhood, etc. as oneself".

Comment: One of the characters in the movie is actually [credited](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0393162/fullcredits/) as "Pinole Guy", which I'm taking to mean he's from Pinole. I'm not sure if he was involved in that conversation. The actor was Darelle Owens a.k.a. rapper Shorty Mack.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen the movie, but it does take place in California, and there is a city named Pinole in California. It could be just referring to the town the boy is from, because one of the definitions of [homey](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/homeboy#homeboy_1) is a "a boy or man from the same town, neighborhood, etc. as oneself".